# MonadState gets stuck in an infinite recursive loop

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

**[EDIT 3]**

I have finally pinned down the problem: I added the put method for the MonadState instance:

```
instance MonadState CPUState VM where
    get = VM get
    put s = do
              liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Modifying state"
              liftIO $ putStrLn.show $ (ip s)
              state (\_ -> ((),s))
```

The infinite loop starts whenever the state needs to be updated:

```
let s' = (cpuState { ip = (ip cpuState) + 1 })
put s'
```

I am not really sure why... Could anyone please be kind enough to clarify why it keeps on recursively calling the put method?

**[EDIT 2]**

Now I know why it's hanging, and it's all due to this single line:

```
modify $ \s -> (cpuState { globalMemory = newGlobalMemory, ip = currentIP + 1 })
```

Before I made the newtype, this was working perfectly... How would I implement the same method on the MonadState instance?

**[EDIT 1]**

Thanks chi! I actually did something similar:

```
newtype VM a = VM{
    unwrapVM :: RWST [Quadruple] [String] (CPUState) IO a
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO,
             MonadRWS [Quadruple] [String] CPUState)

instance MonadReader [Quadruple] VM where
    ask = VM ask

instance MonadWriter [String] VM where
    tell = VM . tell

instance MonadState CPUState VM where
    get = VM get
```

This compiles, but when I evaluate the RWST, it just hangs there indefinitely

I actually tried doing it your way, but I get the following compile errors (even with GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving):

```
• Expecting one more argument to ‘VM’
  Expected a type, but ‘VM’ has kind ‘* -> *’
• In the first argument of ‘MonadWriter’, namely ‘VM’
```

**[Original Question]**

Given a newtype that wraps an RWST:

```
newtype VM a = VM{
    unwrapVM :: RWST [Quadruple] [String] (CPUState) IO a
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)
```

Why isn't it possible to do something like this?

```
startVM :: [Quadruple] -> Memory -> Memory -> IO ()
startVM quads globalMemory localMemory = 
    do 
      (a,w) <- evalRWST (unwrapVM $ runVM) quads (setInitialCPUState globalMemory localMemory) 
      mapM_ (putStrLn) $ w 

runVM :: VM ()
runVM = do
          quadruples <-  ask     . . . .    [1] 
          cpuState <-  get       . . . .    [2]
          return ()
```

Haskell complains in runVM that there is no instance for MonadReader [1] and for MonadState [2], however it's clearly not that way, since VM is just a wrapper for a RWST, right?

Comment: Advice for future questions: (1) Please don't make edits that radically change the original question, or that add separate questions, specially if someone has already answered (invalidating correct answers is not nice). If you have further questions, it is better to either leave comments to the answer asking for clarification, for smaller issues, or to post a new question, for bigger issues. (2) If you add extra information to a question, don't do it in reverse chronological order, as it makes the question very hard to read.

Comment: I'll be more conscious next time. Thank you Duplode

Comment: No worries :) It may take a little while to get used to the conventions of this place, but it's all for the best (i.e. posts that will hold long-lasting value as reading material).

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly ask for the needed instances to be inherited.

```
newtype VM a = VM{
    unwrapVM :: RWST [Quadruple] [String] (CPUState) IO a
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadState, MonadReader)
                                               -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For this you probably need the extension `GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving`.

You need to be explicit on inheriting these instances, since otherwise you could define your own

```
instance MonadState VM where ...
instance MonadReader VM where ...
```

Indeed, it is *very* common to wrap an existing type `T` under a `newtype W` only to provide `W` with a *different* instance than the one for `T`.

Comment: thank you chi! Please take a look at my updated question :-)

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop was due to me calling state inside the put. I just changed it to:

```
instance MonadState CPUState VM where
    get = VM get
    put s = VM . put $ s
```

For anyone that wants to hide the nested monad transformers, this is the way to go:

```
newtype VM a = VM{
    unwrapVM :: RWST [Quadruple] [String] (CPUState) IO a
} deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO,MonadRWS [Quadruple] [String] CPUState)

instance MonadReader [Quadruple] VM where
    ask = VM ask

instance MonadWriter [String] VM where
    tell = VM . tell

instance MonadState CPUState VM where
    get = VM get
    put s = VM . put $ s
```